# How to loop through named cells and list value for each

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to get the value of each named cell. I started with the code below.
Its able to list cells with names but does not show the correct value. In the variable `n.value` I get a reference such as `=Orders!$G$8`, whereas I was expecting $25 because $25 is what the cell really contains.

**The question is:**

How to get the value contained using the "Names" collection in the for loop?

**Code:**

```
Sub ListVarsWithValue()
    Dim n As Name
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim s As String
    s=""
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        s = s +  n.Name + "=" + n.Value + chr(10) '<-- n.value not OK
    Next n
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: is the name cell a range of cells or just one cell?

Comment: Good question. In this case, the name refers to a single cell. However, it would be nice to know how to know if it refers to a range. Maybe I could add an IF statement to check the RefresToRange?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't ActiveSheet instead of ActiveWorkBook?

Comment: @mhyst, ActiveWorkbook is a superset that contains all sheets - I am not getting compile error. The error is that the value stored in the property "value" is a range not a plain value.

Comment: Then you should print all the names to see what is the problem. Perhaps there are some names whose value you cannot change. Or perhaps you have to consider each name as a Range object and then use n.Range(1,1).value or n.Range("A1").value

Comment: Consider giving the **EoinS** answer the checkmark.............it is the better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name represents a defined name for a range of cells.  When you run this on your activeworkbook you are going to pull Print_Areas and xlfn.countifs_ and other weird name objects you didn't even know about.  Also if your range is more than one cell then range(n.value).value will not work.  There are two many unknowns to try to pull value for each name.

I would throw a test in your sub to make sure there is a value.  This is quick and dirty but you get the idea.

```
Sub sdf()
On Error Resume Next ''shouldn't use this but demonstrates how to get what you need
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
If Not IsError(Range(n.Value).Value) Then  ''just try something like this
Debug.Print n.Name & n.Value & Range(n.Value).Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the Value of a Name is its augmented Address in formula form..............you need:

```
Sub ListVarsWithValue()
    Dim n As Name
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim s As String
    s = ""
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        s = s & n.Name & "=" & n.Value & "-" & Range(n.Value).Value & vbCrLf
    Next n
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

The logic is:

`Range(n.Value).Value` is like:
`Range("Sheet4!$B$4").Value` is like:
`bee` which is the actual cell content!

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I think the property name "Value" is a bit misleading...

Comment: @NoChance  Consider marking **EoinS**'s answer as the best answer.

Comment: I will. His answer pointed out an important point indeed. Your remark is beautiful (I have no other description now!). Thx.